# How do I get the numbers in a String and then calculate the average of them?

Tags: java, arrays, string, java-stream

So I am currently experimenting with Streams and I try to calculate the average of the numbers in the String "589 Hello 56" in a stream.
My approach is like this:

```
List <int[]> experiment = a.stream()
    .map(x -> x.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "").split("\\D+"))
    .map(x-> Arrays.asList(x).stream().mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

So I first get a Stringarray with "589 56", because I split the String. 
But after that I try to convert everything to an Integerarray to get the average more easily and it doesn´t work, because the "589 56" converts to "58956".
Does anyone have a better approach? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want to fetch all numbers from the string, then calculate the average of them?

Comment: The number gathering is a different operation...not sure why you would like to include it in any-stream-processing. Once you have those, you can stream the list and do whatever you want with them.

Comment: @ marstran Yes I want to fetch all the numbers. So in this case it would be "589" and "56". And than I want to calculate the average of these two which is (589+56)/2 = 322.5

Comment: Try this `Arrays.stream(s.split("\\D+"))
                .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                .average();`

Comment: *FYI:* `[^0-9]` and `\D` is the same thing, so you first remove all non-digit characters, then try to split on the now non-existent non-digits, which means that split will do thing.

Comment: please learn this [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To calculate the average using stream, you need :

```
double average = Arrays.stream(a.split("\\D+")) // split with non degits ["589", "56"]
        .mapToInt(Integer::valueOf) // convert each string to integer [589, 56]
        .average()  // OptionalDouble
        .getAsDouble(); // double 322.5
```

Or if you are not sure that your string can contain any number, then you need to avoid this with :

```
.orElse(0);
```

or

```
.orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("no number in the string"));
```

instead of `.getAsDouble();`

---

Or if you want to go deeper and for example avoid cases where the numbers can be in front of any non digits for example `a45 Hello 9a7` where the numbers can be a part of a word, in this case you can go with Pattern and Matcher with this regex [`\b\d+\b`](https://regex101.com/r/4HmBol/1), which use work boundary, like so :

```
double average = Pattern.compile("\\b\\d+\\b")
        .matcher(a)
        .results()
        .map(MatchResult::group)
        .mapToInt(Integer::valueOf)
        .average()
        .orElse(0);
```

This last solution can work only from Java9+.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
String s = "589 Hello 56";
OptionalDouble average = Arrays.stream(s.split("\\D+"))
            .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)// or maybe  .mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble)
            .average();
```

Answer (score 0):

The call to replaceAll strips all non-numeric characters from the string including the spaces. This converts '589 Hello 56' into '58956'. Try using `replaceAll("[^0-9\\s]", "")`.

You will also need to split on the separator characters (i.e., the spaces) instead of the digits.

Comment: Well my IDEA sadly says: "Illegal escape character in string literal"

Comment: Thanks for the update but sadly my compiler says: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "123456  789" when i try to convert it into an integerarray